# Is is possible to use email and password in Twitter API instead of API key and secret?

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

The twitter API endpoint (`twitter.com/oauth2/token`) requires API-Key and Secret in Basic Authorization header.

#### Code

```py
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+ str(base64.b64encode('API-KEY:API-SECRET'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')),
}
```

What I would like to do:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+ str(base64.b64encode('MY-EMAIL:MY-PASSWORD'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')),
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: We can help with programming here. If you have questions for accessing and authorizing to a website, please see their docs and contact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Email and password are not suitably secure to be used in Twitter application authentication with the API (and should never be typed into third party apps or services).

Comment: Thank you for responding.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/basic-auth
With reference to this documentation you can see email and password being used for authentication

Comment: Correct, however this documentation refers to the enterprise data APIs and these are not Twitter account usernames and passwords. You cannot use email-based authentication for the Twitter API - use OAuth 2.